# Edit a unique field used as foreignkey in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I have two models, one **Price** and **Market**:

```
class Market(models.Model):
    market_name = models.CharField(max_length=3, unique=True)

class Price(models.Model):
    market = models.ForeignKey(Market, on_delete=models.CASCADE, to_field="market_name")
```

I want to be able to edit the *market_name* field on the **Market** model and have the subsequent *Price* objects updated without causing errors.

```
update or delete on table "appname_market" violates foreign key constraint "appname_price_market_id_5f75a816_fk_appnames" on table "appname_price"
DETAIL:  Key (market_name)=(Cute Martket Name) is still referenced from table "appname_price".
```

Pointing them on the *pk* is one the solution, but I want to stick to using *market_name* as foreignkey for a reason. How would you do that ?

I imagined a method for *pre_save* :

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=Market)
def update_market_field(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        obj = sender.objects.get(pk=instance.pk)
    except sender.DoesNotExist:
        pass  # Object is new, so field hasn't technically changed, \
              # but you may want to do something else here.
    else:
        if not obj.market_name == instance.market_name:  # Field has changed
            Price.objects.filter(market=obj.market_name).update_or_create(market=instance)
```

But this still producing errors because actually the **Market** object hasn't been saved yet. A half solution also is to delete all *Prices* with that *obj.martket_name* in this *pre_save* method, and I have seen that it effectively update the unique field but ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can override the save method to achieve this:

```
class Market(...):

   def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
      prices = None
      if self.pk:
           obj = self.__class__.objects.get(pk=self.pk)
           if obj.market_name != self.market_name:
               prices = obj.price_set.all()
      super().save(*args, **kwargs)
      if prices is not None:
           prices.update(market_id=self.market_name)
```

Comment: Yes. That works with some modifications at the last line to `prices.update(market_id=self.market_name)` . Strangely when saving from an UpdateView it doesn't work whilst saving it from the admin interface it works smoothly. Any hint where I need to look for ?